# Javascript / jQuery - issue disabling validation when field is hidden

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, validation

The following Javascript / jQuery shows a field when one of two different values in a drop down list are selected but hides the field otherwise:

```
    function HideShowChargeCode() {
        var action = $('#<%=ddl_request_action.ClientID %>').val();
        if (action == "3" ||  action == "4") {
            $('#<%=pnl_charge_code.ClientID %>').show();
            document.getElementById("<%=rfv_charge_code.ClientID %>").enabled = true;
        } else {
            $('#<%=pnl_charge_code.ClientID %>').hide();
            document.getElementById("<%=rfv_charge_code.ClientID %>").enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

The second piece of each condition is supposed to control the validation but it doesn't seem to be working as expected. I am still encountering the issue of when the field is hidden, it is still trying to be validated. Any solutions to have the validation turned off when the field is hidden is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, I converted this to a C# function and sure enough, everything works as expected:

```
 protected void ddl_request_action_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var selected = ddl_request_action.SelectedIndex;

            if (selected == 3 || selected == 4)
            {
                pnl_charge_code.Visible = true;
                rfv_charge_code.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                pnl_charge_code.Visible = false;
                rfv_charge_code.Enabled = false;
            }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing in jQuery and vanilla JavaScript. Try changing the code to the following:

```
function HideShowChargeCode() {
    var action = $('#<%=ddl_request_action.ClientID %>').val();
    if (action == "3" ||  action == "4") {
        $('#<%=pnl_charge_code.ClientID %>').show().prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
        $('#<%=pnl_charge_code.ClientID %>').hide().prop("disabled", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Definitely a good tip. I've refactored my code to match yours but am still facing the same issue.

Comment: Does validation happen on the client, or on the server?

Comment: Server side validation

Comment: Well, you can't control the server-side validation through an attribute of the element. If there is a client control that is associated with this element, then you need to toggle the enabled property of that client control.

Comment: posted my solution above